# How to make API request using variables in katalon studio

Tags: groovy, katalon-studio

I'm new to Katalon Studio, I have one requirement that is read data from excel sheet and make an API request. Please provide steps.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Please read through the following threads:

- [read from excel sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44904760/how-to-read-data-from-excel-sheet-in-katalon-studio)
- [parametrize test case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57798753/katalon-test-case-parameterize-with-variable)
- [parametrize web service request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56430247/how-to-passing-json-parameters-for-test-api-restful-in-katalon-studio)

This [Katalon tutorial](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/create_rest_api_requests_manually.html#introduction) is also very useful.

Answer (score 1):

[image: This screenshot will show you how to declare variables and how the data will extract from CSV/Excel file]

1) Variable creation>> Here, we are creating variables
2) Data will retrieve from Excel/CSV >> Choose "Test Data Value" from Type and Select your file and enter column and row number of value from the file.
3) Call Variables>> Use the variables which are created in the first step (Variable creation section